# Simple counter for loops ruby

Tags: ruby

For the ruby .times do is there a counter or do I have to do the following

```
count = 0
4.times do
puts "this is the count #{count}"
count = count+1
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, `times` yields a counter:

```
4.times do |count|
  puts "this is the count #{count}"
end
```

Comment: is there a way to set the initial value of count? say 4 ?

Comment: `(1..4).each { |count| puts "this is the count #{count}" }` or `for count in 1..4
  puts "this is the count #{count}"
end`

Comment: @chell: No, for that you could either add the start value to the count yielded by `times` or use something like `4.upto(7) do |i| ... end` to iterate over the number 4 to 7.

Comment: Thanks sepp2k you are a rock star